# Handle duplicate request on Server side from Client(C# base mobile application)

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, jersey, httprequest

I work on Server side, preparing resources and producing webservices to the Client. 
Now my client is saying he cannot stop user sending duplicate requests to me but what he can do is, allocating a unique token id to each unique request and it will be same if sent multiple times.
At my end I can create a cache(of Hashmap or any other ds) and put the tokenId and Response as Key/Value, On every request I will check if the token Id exists or not in the map, if already present I will send its value(Response) back to Client.
On receiving the response against the token Id, the client will delete that request from its queue to avoid its resending.

MAIN ISSUE :
It looks simple till now right,
Here's the show stopper, My application will be running on 12 UI nodes. It means, every node will have its own instance of cache. And there is no surety that which node will handle and process the Client request, it could be random.

Now the solution came to my mind is Creating a table with TokenId & Response column and presist/check the tokenId on every request. This will work but its too costly to hit database on every single request. That is hack and not a good design I feel.

Please provide your inputs on the same.

Comment: Are 12 UI nodes in fact 12 servers?

Comment: I think yes..I am not that sure how it is managed but yes it has multiple instances of the same application.